# Force PC/SC driver on ACR122U NFC reader

Tags: nfc, rfid, pcsc, acr122, lib-nfc

I have trouble with using my ACR122U RFID card reader form ACS. I need to connect it to my Mac using the PC/SC driver. I installed the driver from the ACS website and confirmed that it's running.

However, whenever I test using the `nfc-list` command, I get the following error:

```
nfc-list uses libnfc libnfc-1.7.1-189-g2869ae2
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb        Unable to claim USB interface (Permission denied)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:020:002
```

As far as I've understood from googling is that it is the Mac taking over the USB that prevents PC/SC using the device, but how can I force the computer to use the PC/SC driver instead of the default Apple USB?

PS: I have installed `libusb`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two different options for connecting the ACR122U to libnfc:

1. You can either use the direct USB driver for the ACR122U, `libnfc.driver.acr122_usb` (which is what you are currently using). In this case, you need to make sure that the PC/SC daemon does not take over control of the reader (since only one instance can access the USB interface of the reader at a time).

   - The quick-and-dirty fix is to disable the PC/SC daemon that takes control over the ACR122U. Though this is not straight forward on Mac OS X, a detailed explanation can be found in [Ludovic's blog](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.co.at/2011/07/pcscd-debug-output-on-mac-os-x.html).
   - Alternatively, you could prevent the PC/SC daemon from taking control over that specific reader by editing `/usr/libexec/SmartCardServices/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Info.plist`. You would need search for the entry

     ```
     <key>ifdProductID</key>
     ```

     Below this entry, there is an array of entries of the form

     ```
     <string>0xXXXX</string>
     ```

     You will need to search for entries containing the values 0x2200, 0x90CC, and 0x2214. Remove those lines, but remember the relative line number (i.e. the offset in the `<array>`). Then, also remove the corresponding lines under

     ```
     <key>ifdVendorID</key>
     ```

     They should all contain the value 0x072F and thus have the form

     ```
     <string>0x072F</string>
     ```

     Moreover, you also need to remove the corresponding lines under

     ```
     <key>ifdFriendlyName</key>
     ```

     All of them will probably start with `<string>ACS`.
2. Alternatively, you could use the PC/SC based libnfc driver for the ACR122U (`libnfc.driver.acr122_pcsc`). This driver uses the system PC/SC daemon to access the reader instead of taking control over the USB interface directly. For this option to work, you need to configure lib-nfc to use the PC/SC driver instead of the direct USB driver. When you compile libnfc yourself, you could do this by explicitly activating only the PC/SC based driver:

   ```
   ./configure --with-drivers=acr122_pcsc
   make
   ```

   However, note that this driver has been depreciated and libnfc authors strongly discourage its use.

Comment: Thank you! This is the single most informative answer I have ever found on the Internet.

Comment: When I edit `/usr/libexec/SmartCardServices/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` (using `sudo`) the contents just revert to the original contents … any clue?

Comment: You've noted that the `acr122_pcsc` driver is deprecated and no longer recommended for use. Is there a preferred way to use `libnfc` with a CCID-compliant PC/SC device? (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61421966)

Comment: @jared no, since there is no NFC support in PC/SC, any libnfc to PC/SC or CCID interface would need to be specific to any (proprietary) reader implementation.

Comment: How do I edit the .plit file? Even after disabling system integrity I don't have enough permission to change anything.