# Force PC/SC driver on ACR1252U NFC reader and enter card emulation mode using python

Tags: python, nfc, macos-catalina, pcsc, lib-nfc

Objective: let ACR1252U NFC reader enter card emulation mode using python on Mac

I have trouble with using the ACS ACR1252U card reader on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 using the PC/SC driver. I installed the driver from the [ACS website](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/driver/342/acr1252u-usb-nfc-reader-iii-nfc-forum-certified-reader/).

By using the pyscard (http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/) library, the following python code works and returns the correct enter card emulation mode response on **windows** computer:  [Enter Card Emulation Mode Command & Response Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyJDr.png)

```
import smartcard

hresult, hcontext = smartcard.scard.SCardEstablishContext( smartcard.scard.SCARD_SCOPE_USER )

hresult, readers = smartcard.scard.SCardListReaders( hcontext, [] )
print(readers)

hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = smartcard.scard.SCardConnect(hcontext, readers[0], smartcard.scard.SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT, 0)

CTL_CODE = smartcard.scard.SCARD_CTL_CODE(3500)

apdu = [0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00]

hresult, response = smartcard.scard.SCardControl( hcard, CTL_CODE, apdu )
```

But it gives an error on Mac. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508174/force-pc-sc-driver-on-acr122u-nfc-reader) answer to change plist files but I still get the same error:

```
python3 nfc.py
['ACS ACR1252 1S CL Reader(1)', 'ACS ACR1252 1S CL Reader(2)']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nfc.py", line 17, in <module>
    hresult, response = smartcard.scard.SCardControl( hcard, CTL_CODE, apdu )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smartcard/scard/scard.py", line 408, in SCardControl
    return _scard.SCardControl(hcard, dwControlCode, inbuffer)
SystemError: <built-in function SCardControl> returned NULL without setting an error
```

I installed libnfc using homebrew but I am not sure how to compile it according to the 2nd part of the answer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you had in success on this in the meantime?

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?