# macOS 10.15.4 - external NFC Reader over USB (CCID & PC/SC compliant) for Host Card Emulation

Tags: linux, nfc, rfid, pcsc, lib-nfc

I have an [Identiv uTrust 3700 F CL Reader](https://support.identiv.com/3700f/) that I can't setup with on macOS Catalina 10.15.4. I would like to read NDEF Tags<del>, use U2F (FIDO2 CTAP1) via NFC,</del> and emulate a card from the reader (for other readers to read, like an Android or iOS device) where my host acts as the secure element.

My reader works great with `opensc-tools` to list the reader. I suspect multiple processes are competing for the USB device.

[This section from libnfc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc#scl3711) indicates a related device (the [SCL3711](https://www.identiv.com/products/smart-card-readers/rfid-nfc-contactless/scl3711/), which is another Identiv contactless-only USB reader) can either choose to not use the proprietary driver or to disable PCSC entirely to use with nfc-tools. However this does not work for me on macOS (or Ubuntu). With the driver installed:

```
% LIBNFC_LOG_LEVEL=3  nfc-list -v
debug   libnfc.config   key: [allow_intrusive_scan], value: [yes]
debug   libnfc.config   Unable to open directory: /usr/local/Cellar/libnfc/1.7.1/etc/nfc/devices.d
debug   libnfc.general  log_level is set to 3
debug   libnfc.general  allow_autoscan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  allow_intrusive_scan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) defined by user
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using arygon driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn532_uart driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using ACR122S driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.driver.acr122_pcsc   PCSC device [Identiv uTrust 3700 F CL Reader] is not NFC capable or not supported by libnfc.
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_pcsc driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn53x_usb driver
No NFC device found.
```

With the driver uninstalled:

```
% sudo LIBNFC_LOG_LEVEL=3  nfc-list -v
debug   libnfc.config   key: [allow_intrusive_scan], value: [yes]
debug   libnfc.config   Unable to open directory: /usr/local/Cellar/libnfc/1.7.1/etc/nfc/devices.d
debug   libnfc.general  log_level is set to 3
debug   libnfc.general  allow_autoscan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  allow_intrusive_scan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) defined by user
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using arygon driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn532_uart driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using ACR122S driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_pcsc driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn53x_usb driver
No NFC device found.
```

[This S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508174/force-pc-sc-driver-on-acr122u-nfc-reader) is seems to offer the same advice:

> ... you could use the PC/SC based libnfc driver for the ACR122U
>   (libnfc.driver.acr122_pcsc). This driver uses the system PC/SC daemon
>   to access the reader instead of taking control over the USB interface
>   directly. For this option to work, you need to configure lib-nfc to
>   use the PC/SC driver instead of the direct USB driver. When you
>   compile libnfc yourself, you could do this by explicitly activating
>   only the PC/SC based driver:
>
> ```
> /configure --with-drivers=acr122_pcsc 
> make
> ```
>
> However, note that this
>   driver has been depreciated and libnfc authors strongly discourage its
>   use.

I can't find the chip in my device but I suspect it is the popular pn53x (device `04e6:5790`).

Is there a preferred method today? Are other tools available to use on Linux and macOS to communicate with NFC readers and tags?

Edit: Although an answer to this question would be required to get NFC to work on macOS, it appears no browser currently supports this on desktop.

Right now I can access the card reader as a regular contactless smartcard reader (CCID via PC/SC) on macOS and Linux, but how can I use an NFC controller to get something like an ATS from an NFC tag instead of an ATR?

Comment: Before you spend time getting it working are you sure this read supports Host Card Emulation, not all readers do and I saw nothing in the datasheet or documentation to say it supports Host Card Emulation, only lots of Cards and P2P

Comment: I also do not see anything guaranteeing support for HCE. I have contacted the vendor. If I cannot use HCE I would still like to read NDEF Tags & use U2F (FIDO2 CTAP1) via NFC.

Comment: So far only I've only seen the acr1252u https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/342/acr1252u-usb-nfc-reader-iii-nfc-forum-certified-reader/ support Host Card Emulation